# How to create a windows cabinet file using Maven 3?

Tags: maven, maven-3, cab

I'm new to Apache Maven and would like to know a way to create a windows cabinet file as part of the maven build life cycle.

I was hoping there would be a plugin for the task, but can't seem to locate one.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** It looks like the Ant Cab task relies on a dependency that no longer exists. Other resources point to using a [Cab creator](https://github.com/grahamrb/CabinetMaker) written in Java, the [lcab](https://packages.debian.org/sid/lcab) tool if you're on Linux, or makecab.exe on Windows. Another option would be to use a zip file, which is more widely supported.

What you're looking for the [AntRun plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) for Maven, which will then give you access to the [Ant Cab task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/cab.html).

Here is an untested example of what you would add to your POM in the plugins section:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>ant-example</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <cab cabfile="target/example.cab" basedir="deploy/folder"/>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: jadez,  This functionality is broken in ant. It looks like I need to refactor ant's cab.java file.

Comment: That is unfortunate. There are some other tools out there for creating cab files, but they don't appear to work directly with Maven.